# How to create nonexistent folder for grouping purposes in C# or ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

More clear about topic : 
In the `Solution Explorer` inside `Visual Studio` I have lot's of code and class files.
We are searching for a way to arrange them. such way that I can add related ones into one folder. No matter if I can achieve this with built-in features or extensions.
However the folder shouldn't really exist or be created at run-time.
Something similar to `namespaces` in the code which is just a ***concept***; they actually don't exist.

**I need this exactly inside project hierarchy space**

Comment: Why do you need the folder to not really exist?

Comment: Because that cause my files to have different physical locations.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Why does the physical location of the files matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Project and Solution are fixed in that projects are always part of the solution. When you add any code file to a folder, that folder name becomes part of the namespace for that code file. I don't see how this should pose a problem. Just go ahead and use the tools as they are designed rather than try to fight them.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-to-structure-visual-studio.html

Comment: This is not a limitation made by me. the project owner has set this for me and he is not allowing me to use alternative ways.

Comment: I don't understand the question - what type of files are you trying to add/organize?

Comment: Should I take a screenshot of what I want so you would understand ? I need a symbolic folder to add files into it.

Comment: Then just create the folder inside the project and add the files? I still don't see the problem so a screenshot might help :-)

Comment: Have you tried some C++ IDE ? My goal is to arrangement my files with folders without physical difference between the files.

Comment: Try using "Solution Folders" -have updated answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Can you check last line of my question ? >> I need this exactly inside project hierarchy space

Comment: It will be in its own project, in a separate solution if you wish. ALL projects and their contents are part of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use the "Add Folder"?  While they exist in the project and a physical folder is created, when you compile the application they don't get added as long as only code files exist in the folder.

Comment: Please check my comment on seageoff answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to create folders under the project directory.  The classes that you put into these folders don't have to follow the folder hierarchy with their namespace but they should.  I am not sure why this should be a limitation as you mention above.

If this was a Visual C++ project, you could create false folders and filters that separate the files just like they do for headers and source files.

Comment: Also, as Justin mentioned, they won't get compiled in your code.  They are there to help you stay organized.  If you have too many classes to keep organized easily, you should be using namespaces with corresponding folders as good practice.

Comment: Because all of files I am keeping in the root of project is not actually class and codes. Can't pass limitation which have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so you have other types of files, including other resources like images or text files?  If so, you should still be able to cite them at runtime even if they are compiled into a folder.  Can you be more specific about your issue?  I still don't see folders as a limitation at runtime.  Also, I am uncertain of what you mean by "Project Space" vs "Solution Space" when it comes to folders?

Comment: I mean with project space is than the folder must be inside project hierarchy not outside as brenton said.

Comment: Mahdi, I see what you mean now.  That is not the wording I understood but I know what you mean.  I don't think there is a way to do this in a C# project without using physical folders.  Like I said above, you can certainly do that in a Visual C++ project but not in a C# project.  The rules between the languages are different.  Don't view this as a limitation but rather a feature because it prevents you doing something that could potentially cause you more more effort down the road.

Comment: I'll wait one day to see if there is any extension for my purpose. your post will be marked as answer if no extension are found in one day or so.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your solution and go to Add -> New Solution Folder.  You should be able to add any files (create new or add existing) inside of these solution folders as necessary (they are meant for solutions, but various types of files can be added.)

This does not create a "real" folder, but it does create sort of a symbolic link for organization.